# Express res.redirect not redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am having trouble using res.redirect() in express.

I have tried looking on other questions but the answers don't really cover my specific problem, or they at least aren't relevant enough.

```
app.get(/\d\w*/g, function (req, res, next) {

    urlCreator.findURL(req.originalUrl,function(smallURL){
       if (smallURL === "Small URL doesn't exist"){
           res.send(smallURL);
       }
       else {
            res.redirect(smallURL);
       }
   });
```

});

When the res.redirect() within the else block gets reached, I get this in my browser (screenshot below) instead of redirecting to whatever the page desired.
The format of smallUrl is for example "www.facebook.com"

[Browser response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzuPh.png)

Am i missing something obvious as to why the browser will not simply redirect and displays this instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the protocol. If you omit `http://` or `https://`, your browser treats the redirect as the name of a local resource - and you don't have one that is called `/www.facebook.com`.

So, just prefix the url with the protocol, and you are fine :-)

Comment: Ahhh of course! Thanks for your help @Golo Roden. That fixed it. Looks like i'm going to have to check and format all URL's to contain a protocol now too! :)